# Where should I ask system customization questions?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I'd like to customize my Finder's Dock (I have a Mac) with Candy bar (an app), but it's not working. Which Stack Exchange site(s) cover Photoshop, system customization, and file handling?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a question (or questions!) for [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com), the Stack Exchange site for users of Apple products. Don’t forget to read [its FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq).

As noted by slhck and studiohack in the comments section, for general user questions about software and hardware you can also ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com), which is not Apple-specific. Don’t forget to read [its FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: Well, and just to mention it, there's also [SU]. Because we also do Mac.

Comment: to second @slhck, yes, we have SU, we do computer *hardware* & *software*.